# Migrating data from Netezza to Redshift

Tags: database-migration, amazon-redshift, netezza

I am not sure if this is the correct forum, but any help on this would be really appreciated.

Can someone please share some links/references which could help me in analyzing the feasibility of database migration from IBM Netezza to Amazon Redshift?

Answer (score 4):

Kamlesh,

There are a lot of similarities between both technologies: IBM Pure Data/Netezza and AWS Redshift.

Some developers who worked on the first version of Netezza also worked on the first version of ParAccel DB. AWS Redshift utilizes the same core engine as ParAccel DB. ParAccel has been sold and the product has been re-branded as Actian Matrix. Still, the core engine is the same.

Both databases are MPP implementations, with a shared nothing architecture. Both share a PostgreSQL "heritage". AWS Redshift truly is a "columnar" database, while Netezza is not.

There are a few differences in SQL Syntax and also some differences in functionality. There are several features/capabilities that AWS Redshift does not yet have. Some of the most "noteworthy" differences is the fact that Redshift does not support Stored Procs, User Defined Functions or Sequences.

[Amazon AWS lists the differences between AWS Redshift and PostgreSQL in this documen](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html)t.  While this is not a comparison between Netezza and Redshift it will give you a good idea of "what to expect" in terms of differences since both Netezza and Redshift were both originally based on postgreSQL.